# How do I configure a multi-sig as the update authority of a program?

Tags: multisig

Now as I am getting some real users I am thinking to move away from the single update authority to the multi-sig, preferably squads. Is there a tutorial on same?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, definitely checkout Squads! It's an open-source multisig on Solana with amazing docs and is built by a really great team. If you follow the step-by-step guide linked below, you should be good.

In short, the steps to setup the multisig authority are:

1. Create a multisig and setup your signers.
2. Register your program with the multisig.
3. Use the Solana CLI to change your program's update authority to the multisig account.
4. Done!

Now to upgrade your program, you simply need to:

1. Write the new program executable bytes to a buffer account.
2. Create a new "deployment" from the multisig.
3. Get all the required signatures from the people on your multisig.
4. Done!

https://docs.squads.so/squads-v3-docs/navigating-your-squad/programs